# Refresh Current View Controller Data Request when XIB Button Clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I want to make error handling pages to all of my view controller through, so when error fetching data error, it's not only showing dialog, but showing a XIB files that contain error message and button to refresh. Like this:

[image]

Here's the XIB Class code:

```
import UIKit

class ErrorMessage: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewError: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTryAgain: UIButton!
    static var message: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        labelError.text = ErrorMessage.message
    }

    @IBAction func didTapTryAgain(_ sender: Any) {
        Dialog.showProgressDialog(info: "")
    }
}
```

Here's my base controller code, who handling all the problem.

```
import Foundation

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var uiView =  UIView();

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
    }

}
```

And here's how I call it in another class which I extend `BaseViewController`, so it can show the error problem globally, without I redeclared again the class:

```
func onFailedDeleteCart(errorMessage: String) {
        getErrorMessage(message: errorMessage)
    }
```

Right now I can pass the error message.

**The problem is, I want the Refresh button refreshing current View Controller when I click it. Maybe calling current View Controller's viewDidLoad when I click it will be the nice logic but I don't know how to implement it in XIB class.** Anyone can solve out this? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `completion handler` or `delegate` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach: 1**

**Step:1 Create closure for callback**

```
typealias RefreshBlock = (()->())?
```

**Step:2 Define closure in your `UIView` class**

**Step:3 Call closure if user tap refresh button**

```
class ErrorMessage: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewError: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTryAgain: UIButton!
    var refreshBlock:RefreshBlock!
    static var message: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        labelError.text = ErrorMessage.message
    }

    // Step : 3
    @IBAction func didTapTryAgain(_ sender: UIButton) {
        refreshBlock!()
    }
}
```

**Step:4 Assign value in closure when `addSubview` called**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
        viewErrorMessage.refreshBlock = {()
            self.viewDidLoad()
            print("Refresh Contents")
        }   
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
    }

}
```

**Approach: 2**

Pass your current `UIViewController` Reference into `UIView` class. Refer below code.

```
class ErrorMessage: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewError: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTryAgain: UIButton!
    var currentVC:UIViewController!
    static var message: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        labelError.text = ErrorMessage.message
    }

    @IBAction func didTapTryAgain(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentVC.viewDidLoad()
    }
}


class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
        viewErrorMessage.currentVC = self
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great. But, how to access viewErrorMessage.refreshBlock = {()
        print("Refesh contents")
    } from another view controller? So I can do request there

Comment: viewErrorMessage.refreshBlock = {()
            print("Refesh contents")
 } is already in UIViewController

Comment: oh sorry, I put viewErrorMessage.refreshBlock = {() print("Refesh contents") } on my base controller which extend UIViewController. I want to access that in another controller which I extend my BaseController